# Converting Array of objects to arrays of key, value array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I Have a JSON input format, here's an exemple :

```
{
  "friends": [
    {
      "id": "5a8d4euyiuyiuyhiuyc022c7158d5",
      "name": "Gloria Coffey"
    },
    {
      "id": "5a8d4e2rytuyiyuyiytiy3e426",
      "name": "Shawn Ellison"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would transform it to an array key: value arrays, something like this :

```
[[id : "5a8d4euyiuyiuyhiuyc022c7158d5", name:"Gloria Coffey"],[id : "5a8d4e2rytuyiyuyiytiy3e426", name:"Shawn Ellison"]]
```

What I have done :

```
search(event) {
    this.searchRmpmService.getResults(event.query).then(data => {
    this.results = data.friends;
    console.log(this.results);
    let output = [];
    output= Object.entries(this.results);
    console.log(output);
});
```

the first console.log of `this.results` prints me an array of objects

then my `output` array prints:

```
0:Array(2)
0:"0" <-- ??
1:{
   id:"5a8d4e2ffead0c022c7158d5",
   name:"Gloria Coffey"
}length:2__proto__:Array(0)
```

what I would is

```
id : 5a8d4e2ffead0c022c7158d5
name : Gloria Coffey
```

Comment: JavaScript does not have anything that is like `[id : "5a8d4euyiuyiuyhiuyc022c7158d5", name:"Gloria Coffey"]`.

Comment: Javascript does not have key-value arrays, only flat indexed arrays. Your desired result is what you already have at the start. **Instead describe the problem you're trying to solve.**

Comment: Looks like that "friends" property already is an array of objects. It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I suggest you take a step back and write **in words** what steps you need to solve your problem. Pretend that you are teaching another person how to do it. Tell them the steps they need to follow to get the results you want. Write these steps down. After you have a clear idea of the steps required, then you can translate them into JavaScript.

Comment: You can go with `Object.values(data)`, but also you have to define the case if `Object.values(data)` is undefined, then you want to return empty array.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible. The nearest solution of what you want to would be something like this:

```js
let friends = [
    {
      id: "5a8d4euyiuyiuyhiuyc022c7158d5",
      name: "Gloria Coffey"
    },
    {
      id: "5a8d4e2rytuyiyuyiytiy3e426",
      name: "Shawn Ellison"
    }
]

function convert(param) {
  let res = {}
  for (let item of param) {
    let id = item.id
    res[id] = item.name
  }
  return res
}

console.log(convert(friends))
```

This is not an array, but you can access it like:

```
let myObj = convert(friends)
console.log(myObj['5a8d4euyiuyiuyhiuyc022c7158d5'])
```

I hope this will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it by using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) like this:

```js
function flattenArrayToObject(arr) {
  let entries = arr.map(el => [el.id, el.name])
  let obj = Object.fromEntries(entries)
  return obj;
}
```

Or in a one liner if you really needed to:

```js
let flattenArray = arr => Object.fromEntries(arr.map(el => [el.id, el.name]))
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
let friends = [
    {id: "158d5", name: "Gloria"},
    {id: "3e426", name: "Shawn"}
]

function flattenArrayToObject(arr) {
  let entries = arr.map(el => [el.id, el.name]) // [["158d5","Gloria"], ["3e426","Shawn"]]
  let obj = Object.fromEntries(entries)
  return obj;
}

console.log(flattenArrayToObject(friends))
```